# powershell command to reinstall single Windows 10 app

Tags: powershell

I use several one line powershell commands in our servers batch file login script but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with this one.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-AppxPackage -allusers *Windows.Photos* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register '$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml'}"
```

When I try to run this I get the error:
Cannot find path 'C:\$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml'

I am guessing there is a problem with the quoting in the command but I have tried different ways and can't get it to work. If I run the command below from a powershell prompt it works fine.

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers *Windows.Photos* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

I would like to avoid having to create a separate .ps1 file and keep it in a one liner if possible.

Comment: Your ending single quote and double quote syntax is incorrect in the first command.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I figured I was doing something wrong with the quotes but no matter what combinations of double or single quotes I try I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In powershell, strings in single quotes (literal strings) are treated slightly differently to those in double quotes (interpolated strings).

To see this, consider the following

```
$name = "Jones"
'Hello $name'
"Hello $name"
```

This will output:

```
Hello $name
Hello Jones
```

Notice how the variable was not expanded in the single quoted (literal) string, but was expanded in the double quoted (interpolated string)

Back to your issue, the problem is the `Register` argument on `Add-AppxPackage`  has single quotes around what should be an interpolated string.  To escape the double quotes in a batch file, you'll need to use two consecutive double quotes (i.e. `""`). In other words, replace

```
-Register '$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml'
```

with

```
-Register ""$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml""
```

Comment: Alex, thanks for your reply. When I try the command with double quotes as suggested I now receive the error:  The string is missing the terminator: ".

Comment: The complete command I am trying now is:    `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *Windows.Photos* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register ""$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml""}"`